# How to have information show in one row in a certain column while populating multiple rows in other columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I am using SQL Server Mgmt Studio

I have not been able to find my answer on google or stackoverflow, possibly due to phrasing.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to get there to be just one date with empty fields below it in the date (column1), but I'm also trying to group by column2 with a count in column3. I am also trying to get column4, column5, and column6 with different counts on the first row and blank fields underneath (similar to the date column).

**How I have tried to do it**

I have tried to use "partition by", but it just gives me a '1' in all the rows of my column, instead of just a count in the first row with the rest of the column left blank. I may not have written correctly, but I no longer have the code I used to give an example for that.

I have also tried to do a subquery, but it gives me the same count through the entire column in every row.

I am showing you my current output with the code I used to get it, along with my desired output.

My data currently looks like this:

```
Date       | Bucket |  #InBucket  
2017-03-08 |  NULL  |    300 
2017-03-08 |   A    |     27     
2017-03-08 |   B    |      0
2017-03-08 |   c    |      4
2017-03-08 |   D    |      6
```

The query I used to get this data is:

```
select convert(date, getdate(), 101) as [Date], dpcd.bucket, count(*) as [# in Bucket]

from mytable dpcd

where convert(date, getdate(), 101) = convert(date, deletedon, 101)


group by bucket
order by Bucket
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
Date       | Bucket |  #InBucket  |  column4  |  column5  |  colum6
2017-03-08 |  NONE  |    300      |    400    |    200    |   500
           |   A    |     27      |           |           |  
           |   B    |      0      |           |           | 
           |   c    |      4      |           |           |
           |   D    |      6      |           |           |
```

Long explanation, I apologize. Is what I am trying to do even possible? I don't have a lot of experience in SQL, so any and all help would be appreciated.

Is there already a question that has the answer I am searching for? If so, could you direct me to the question? I have not been able to find the answer.

Comment: You should do this type of reformatting in the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this in SQL, but such presentation-layer changes are better done in the application layer.

However, you can do it using `row_number()` and `order by`:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then [Date] end) as [Date],
       bucket, [# in Bucket]
from (select convert(date, getdate(), 101) as [Date],
             dpcd.bucket, count(*) as [# in Bucket],
             row_number() over (order by bucket) as seqnum
      from mytable dpcd
      where convert(date, getdate(), 101) = convert(date, deletedon, 101)
      group by bucket
     ) d
order by Bucket;
```

Comment: This worked for the date field. Thank you very much. Is there a way to do it again in the same query for a column that is a count?

Comment: @jgord . . . This logic will work for any field.  If it is not obvious, you can ask another question with sample data and desired results.